# Erro 404 ao rodar jersey no apache tom-cat

Tags: java, java-ee

Estou utilizando jersey mais toda vez que mando rodar da erro: 404 no apache tom-cat.

```
package br.com.gomes.LojaDeVendas.util;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
// chamando o pacote do service

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("rest")

public class LojaDeVendasResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig{

 public LojaDeVendasResourceConfig(){

packages("br.com.gomes.LojaDeVendas.service");
   }
}

//chamado o conteiner para retorna a resposta abaixo no browser
package br.com.gomes.LojaDeVendas.service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

// http://localhost:8080/LojaDeVendas/rest/vendas
@Path("vendas")
public class LojaDeVendasService {

    @GET
    public String exibir() {
        return "Curso de Java";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal foi mal não precisam responder já encontrei o problema o endereço da http:localhos:8080/Vendas/rest/vendas no local de Vendas digitei LojaDeVendas e foi ai onde eu errei, o código  já esta funcionando corretamente